# AttributeError: 'Grid' object has no attribute 'tk'

Tags: python, tkinter, attributeerror

Who can help me to find this error , I will be thankful.

```
from tkinter import*
import math

root = Tk()
root.title("Jupiter Notebook Calculator")
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)
root.geometry("452x580+500+40")

mainFareme = Frame(root, bd=20, bg='gainsboro',relief=RIDGE)
mainFrame = Grid()


innerFareme = Frame(root, bd=10, bg='gainsboro',relief=RIDGE)
innerFrame = Grid()
class Calc():
    def __init__(self):
        self.total =0
        self.current =""
        self.firsnum=""
        self.secondnum=""
        self.input_value = True
        self.check_sum=False
        self.op=""
        self.result=False
        
added_value = Calc()

txtDisplay = Entry(innerFrame, font=('arial',18,'bold'), bd=10, width=28, justify=RIGHT)
txtDisplay.grid (row=0, column=0, columnspan=4, pady=1)
txtDisplay.insert(0, "0")

numberpad = "789456123"
i = 0
btn = []
for j in range(3 , 6):
    for k in range(3):
        btn.append(Button(innerFrame, width=6, height =2,font=('arial',18,'bold'), bd=7, text= numberpad[i] )) 
        btn[i].grid(row=j,column = k, pady=1) 
     

root.mainloop()
```

This is the error generated by the code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/foo.py", line 28, in <module>
    txtDisplay = Entry(innerFrame, font=('arial',18,'bold'), bd=10, width=28, justify=RIGHT)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.15/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/tkinter/__init__.py", line 3035, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, 'entry', cnf, kw)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.15/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2566, in __init__
    BaseWidget._setup(self, master, cnf)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.15/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2535, in _setup
    self.tk = master.tk
AttributeError: 'Grid' object has no attribute 'tk'
```

Comment: I'd guess your question could be difficult to find for interested readers w/o having `python` and `anaconda(3)` Tags

Answer (score 0):

`mainFrame` and `innerFrame` are an instance of `Grid`. An instance of `Grid` isn't a widget so you can't use it as the parent of another widget. A widget's parent (or master) must be a widget.

Comment: Thanks for your time , I found the problem..